# Variable html column height dependent on contents

Tags: html, css, dynamic

In order to create a column which expands relative to the amount of data within it up to a maximum height, I have implemented the following approach;

```
.container { 
    max-height: 1000px;
}

.column-body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="column-body">
        Variable amounts of data
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the height of the column remains fixed to the height of the window and doesn't change based on the amount of content. How can I achieve the behaviour I desire from the approach I'm taking?

Comment: Try using height: auto;
Also, if you can create a JSFiddle demonstrating your problem, it is much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `overflow-y: auto` to the container instead.

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/nezekohiwe/1/)